# Use of xcassets versus design team

Tags: xcode, xcasset

Design team provide a folder with all the images required for a project.

I've create xcassets for the icon and splash files,  and for some images who require slicing, etc

I've notices that all the image in xcassets have been duplicate in the xcassets folder.

My question:

1. From xcassets, can I link to image, instead of having xcode
   duplicate it?
2. If link not possible, what are the best way to work with design
   team?
3. Do you thing that, at compile time, xcode will insert just one copy
   of the image?

Thanks for your infos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of xcassets is to consolidate all of your project assets into a nice bundle. I tend to split into multiple xcassets for larger projects. After you pop everything to xcassets, you can get rid of other asset instances from your project.

In compile time, only the files selected in the "add to target" field will be copied over.

Just stick all your files into xcassets, don't add them anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

yes ofcourse there is one tool for your problem's solution

[image]

[AVXCassets Generator](https://github.com/angelvasa/AVXCAssets-Generator)

Hope you will like it